# What is the actual difference between assertEquals() vs assertTrue() in TestNG?

Tags: testng

I'm confusing about both these methods, because both can do the same thing, like below snippet of my code.

Using **assertEquals()**

```
String a = "Hello";
String b = "Hello";

assertEquals(a, b);
```

Using **assertTrue()**

```
assertTrue(a.equals(b));
```

Can anyone tell me the actual difference between both these two methods?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`assertEquals` is better because it gives the unit test framework more information about what you're actually interested in. That allows it to provide better error information when the test fails.

Suppose you had

```
String a = "Hello";
String b = "Hi";
```

Then the test failures might look something like:

```
// From assertEquals(a, b)
Error: Expected "Hi"; was "Hello"

// From assertTrue:
Error: Expected true; was false
```

Which of those do you think gives you more information, bearing in mind that the values would probably be the result of reasonably complex computations?

(These are made up error messages as I don't have testng installed, but they're the *kind* of thing unit test frameworks give.)

Comment: Also, `assertEquals(a, b)` is null-safe, `assertTrue(a.equals(b))` is not.

Comment: Thanks, @Jon for better explanation and for clearing my concept about these two methods.:-)