# verify part of text in a selenium test

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, verification

I use selenium to register something on a customer in my system. 
The response is what I want to make sure the test is ok.

The response is:

```
<div class="ui-messages-info ui-corner-all">
<span class="ui-messages-info-icon"></span>
<ul>
<li>
<span class="ui-messages-info-summary">Name Name was registered -   torsdag 02.03.2017 kl. 09.38.</span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to verify that the text "was registered" is present, and the test to fail if the text is not present.

How can I write a check for that in selenium?

I was thinking something like this:

```
WebElement verify = driver.findElement(By.something("was registered"));
```

Comment: refer this question and answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41974209/what-is-the-actual-difference-between-assertequals-vs-asserttrue-in-testng

Answer (score 0):

```
String el_text = driver.findElement(By.class("ui-messages-info-summary")).getText();
```

and then check if its inside

```
if "was registered" is in el_text:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'was registered')]")
```

If this element is present that means it has text "Was registered".